# Is it possible to verify yesterday transactions using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have a requirement.
Day 1 : I need to post a transaction and transaction process through nightly basis.
Day 2: I need to verify the Day 1 transaction.
How can I achieve this using selenium ?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Manually how are you able to test those transactions? Do you use DB queries or web tables to show those transactions? You may need to schedule the scripts to run like Day 1 script before the nightly batch and wait till the nightly batch is done if it's not so long time then run day 2 scipt.

Comment: Manually  By web tables. How to schedule the scripts as Day 1 and day 2

Comment: I never tried one, may be you can use Jenkins if your scripts are saved in Source tree or similar. Also you can try looking here for some examples of how to schedule https://www.techbeamers.com/run-selenium-tests-using-task-scheduler-windows7/

Comment: how to validate transactions on Day 2 by using date? I only have option to verify by date or transaction amount. do we need to use date()?

Comment: you can use as follows.   Date date = new Date(); SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); String formattedDate = sdf.format(date); System.out.println(formattedDate); String expectedDate="05-15-2020"

if (formattedDate == expectedDate){  println("transaction successfull") }else{  println("transaction failed") }  The expected date is the date you get from the transaction table

Comment: Thank you . I will work on the code .

Comment: How to format Monday, May. 25, 2020, 2:13:31 PM CDT to mm/dd/yyyy . When  try to use Simple Date Format I 'm getting java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Monday, May. 25, 2020, 2:43:23 PM CDT"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)